# What does it mean for semiconductor work function to be p-type or n-type

Tags: semiconductor-physics

I want to know what're n-type and p-type semiconductor work function, the difference of work function between semiconductor and metal, and how to calculate n-type and p-type semiconductor work function. Thanks a lot!

As for calculation of n-type and p-type semiconductor work function, I find some answers on the internet:

> For any semiconductor, n-type, or p-type, you can calculate the work function (Φ_SEMI) using the following equation:

> $Φ_{SEMI} = χ + (E_{VBM} - E_F)$

> Where:

> $Φ_{SEMI}$ is the work function of the semiconductor;
> $χ$ is the electron affinity of the semiconductor;
> $E_{VBM}$ is the energy of the valence band maximum;
> $E_F$ is the energy of the Fermi level.

> For n-type semiconductors, the Fermi level ($E_F$) is closer to the conduction band minimum ($E_{CBM}$), so the value of ($E_{VBM}$ - $E_F$) will be negative (lower work function).

> For p-type semiconductors, the Fermi level ($E_F$) is closer to the valence band maximum ($E_{VBM}$), so the value of ($E_{VBM}$ - $E_F$) will be positive (higher work function).

I think the calculation above is not right, but I confuse what's the exact answer.

Answer (score 0):

The quoted equation and accompanying text are wrong. (The text isnt even a correct description of the incorrect equation.)

$\phi=E_{vac}-E_f$

$\chi=E_{vac}-E_c$

Therefore

$\phi=\chi+E_c-E_f$

As you can see above. There is nothing special about n type and p type calculations for work function.